# renaming multiple worksheets from list using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and am trying to name worksheets from a list.  I have a file with 133 worksheets and want to name each sheet from a list in one of the worksheets.  Cells B1 thru B133 has a list of the desired names, cells c1 through c133 has sheet names (Sheet1 through Sheet 133).  I've tried 2 different codes to no avail.  What am I missing?

Here's an excerpt of what columns B & C look like.

```
File details                    Sheet 1
Sheet Names                     Sheet 23
Calc Notes                      Sheet 2
Rank comparison - baseline      Sheet 3
Trend - Top 30 ct vs baseline   Sheet 5
Trend - Top 30 dur vs baseline  Sheet 6
Trend - Top 30 MTBF vs baseline Sheet 7
Trend - Top 30 ct_dur vs base   Sheet 8
Avail, MTBeF, MTTR scorecard    Sheet 10
Avail, MTBeF, MTTR - Excluded   Sheet 11
All-in vs Excluded              Sheet 12
Summary all lines - count            Sheet 13
Summary all lines - duration    Sheet 14
fault - count                   Sheet 15
fault - duration                Sheet 16
gap count-query vs fault sum    Sheet 17
gap duration-query vs fault sum Sheet 18
missing faults                  Sheet 20
query                           Sheet 9
Prod unit ref                   Sheet 21
Pd Wk ref                       Sheet 22
Query ref                       Sheet 4
FTT                             Sheet 19
```

**#1 (runtime error '424')**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
x = 1
y = 133

For z = 1 To 133
sheetz.Name = Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(y, 2))
Next z


End Sub
```

**#2 (runtime error '91')**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim z As Integer

    For z = 1 To 133
        If ws.Name = Sheetz Then
            Sheetz.Name = Cells(z, 2)
        End If
        Exit For
    Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: Well for one I don't see Sheetz defined anywhere in your code. Do you have it defined somewhere else?

Comment: No I don't.  I assumed defining z would work.  Since Sheetz is intended to be variable, how would it be defined?

Comment: in this case you should use something like this: `Sheets(z).Name = Cells(z, 2)` or `Sheets("Sheet" & z).Name = Cells(z, 2)`

Comment: why is your code in a Worksheet_SelectionChange event ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
Sub test()
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each oldName In ThisWorkbook.Workseets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C133")
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(oldName.Value).Name = oldName.Offset(0, -1).Value
   Next
End Sub
```

Note, that your `C1:C133` range should contain sheet names without quotes (correct: `Sheet1`, uncorrect: `"Sheet1"`)

Comment: Thanks Simico, but no luck.  No error codes, just no changes to sheet names.

Comment: I've upd my answer. Try to specify correct sheet name in line `ThisWorkbook.Workseets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C133")` (change `"Sheet1"` to sheet name where your data stores)

Comment: Thanks again, but no avail.  I know there's something simple I'm missing.  I updated my question with a sample of columns B & C ... in this case the data is stored in Sheet 23.  I've tried that and the sheet name but neither worked.  Frustrating but thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) are you sure that in your column `C` correct sheet names - like `Sheet 1` with space (not `Sheet1`)? 2) try to delete line `On Error Resume Next` on my code and what message will you get?

Comment: I confirmed the sheet names do have a space between "sheet" and "number"; I also confirmed a text format; when I remove the line On Error Resume Next, I get a runtime error '9' (subscript out of range).

Comment: Run please following code: `Sub test2(): For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets: Debug.Print sh.Name: Next: End Sub`, then open _Immediate window_ by pressing __CTRL+G__ and show what data would you get (screenshot will be the best)

Comment: Ok, your code worked as written.  Thanks for your patience.  I found a few things on my end I did wrong ... I was using CodeName references vs SheetName, and out of order.  All's good now, thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub RenameSheets()
    For i = 1 To 133
        On Error Resume Next
        oldname = Cells(i, 3).Value
        newname = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Sheets(oldname).Name = newname
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the thing that's throwing the error is `Sheetz`. The index of the sheet should be in parentheses i.e. `Sheet(z)`